# LabVIEW Report Generation Toolkit: Is there a standard report generation directory?

Tags: labview

Using the LabVIEW RGT, the report didn't show up in the directory in which the vi was called. Is there another folder where this would show up, like the programs folder for the LabVIEW SW? The following code was used: New Report.vi (using Standard Report) -> AppendTextToReport.vi -> DisposeReport.vi.

Answer (score 1):

You must use **Save Report to File.vi** with specified file path to save report to disk. Otherwise it is seems, that report is kept in memory.